# Pointer to a dictionary<> in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class, which its constructor is below

```
public GroupsForm(ref Dictionary<string, List<string>> groupsList)
```

I want to use the groupsList in other functions as well so I declared a private member in the class:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _groupsList;
```

But the problem is when I do `_groupsList = groupsList;`  it makes a copy of the `groupsList` and changes made to `_groupsList` doesn't change `groupsList`, as I think it makes a deep copy by default. What I want is that it should point to that list.

In C++, this can easily be done via pointers, but can anyone tell me how can I do this in C#?

---

Ahmed has posted this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5fFG.png):

[image: Debug session showing _groupsList.Count==3, whilst groupsList.Count==0]

Comment: I see you've posted an image as a reply comment to people. It would be a lot more helpful to copy & paste more of this code and edit it into your question - especially as the problem seems to be in your `InitGroups` method which you haven't even mentioned as yet.

Comment: @Damien, thanks, yes the problem was in initgroups which is solved now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your InitGroups method, you've got an assignment statement to _groupsList - it's this new list that contains 3 items. You could change InitGroups to do something like:

```
var newGroups = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)ser.ReadObject(reader,true);
foreach(var kvp in newGroups)
{
    _groupsList.Add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
}
```

And then you'll still be working with the same Dictionary object.

Answer (score 3):

[There are value types and reference types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711899%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). A dictionary is a reference type so whenever assigning a variable that holds a reference type to another, the reference is copied, which means that both variables will be holding the same data. So, if you change the **data**, you should expect it to change on both variables:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = list1;

list2.Add(10);
list1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // should print 1, 2, 3 and 10.
```

However, if you reassign the variable, then you are not changing the data:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = list1;

list2 = new List<int>() { 10, 11, 12 };
list1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // should print 1, 2, 3 only
```

One thing that caught my attention in your code though was that the constructor is expecting a `ref`. This means that you are passing the reference itself by reference, which in C++ would be something like a double pointer (`type**`). You'd do this if, in the snippet above, you want to have this effect:

```
void MethodA(ref List<int> list)
{
    list = new List<int>() { 10, 11, 12 };
}

// ...

List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
MethodA(ref list1);
list1.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x)); // should print 10, 11, 12
```

One more thing -- AFAIK C# doesn't implement deep copies in any of it classes. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I corrected that ref type thing, but please take a look at this image [http://i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg](http://i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg) , I assigned _groupsList = groupsList; then I initialized _groupsList by calling the function initGroups(); But you can see that groupsList is not changed its count is still 0, where as the count of _groupsList is 3. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Ahmed, you do realize, that you are assigning a new value to _groupsList instead of changing its content? InitGroups assigns a new value. Even if you had been using pointers directly wouldn't have changed anything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `ref` in your method signature. Objects are passed by reference anyway.

And no, there is no copying going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I corrected that but please take a look at this image  http://i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg  , I assigned `_groupsList = groupsList;` then I initialized `_groupsList` by calling the function `initGroups();` But you can see that `groupsList` is not changed its count is still 0, where as the count of _groupsList is 3. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is when I do _groupsList = groupsList; it makes a copy of the groupsList

No, it does not. It copies a pointer. List is a reference type.

> as I think it makes a deep copy by default

Think again. Your conclusion is wrong.

`List<T>` is a reference type, so all variables are pointers. Beginner C#, first week, first day, first hour. Go back and read the introduction then look for the error in the rest of your code you do not show us.

Comment: Except, of course, that you're wrong. They're references, not pointers. Pointers do exist in C#, but they're not what we're dealing with here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Is the rudeness of this answer necessary?

Comment: Rudeneyy? Ever hearrd of sarcasm? Or is that something only people a little older still remember and learned in school?

Comment: @TomTom Sorry, but I don't see sarcasm anywhere. It just was plain rude. But I guess that wasn't your purpose...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but please take a look at this image i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg , I assigned _groupsList = groupsList; then I initialized _groupsList by calling the function initGroups(); But you can see that groupsList is not changed its count is still 0, where as the count of _groupsList is 3. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, I can see why he thought his sarcasm was okay here. Considering how Ahmed bragged about pointers and C++ but failed to understand the basics of C# (he overwrote the field in another method).

Comment: @TomTom: Can you please try and not be so... rough... in your answers?  You've apparently got a history of being very rude in your answers, a surprising number of which have gathered enough flags and downvotes to be deleted automatically by the system.  Could you take it a little easier?  For me?  Pretty please?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong on several points.
C# references are totally different from C++.

In short, you should not use `ref` here because it's for propagating assignments made to parameter to the calling code which is not what you mean.

You are wrong assuming there's any kind of copying involved here.
`groupsList` and `_groups ist` are **two references pointing to the same object in memory**.

You'll need to read more about [reference and value types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I corrected that ref type thing, but please take a look at this image [http://i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg](http://i56.tinypic.com/rs61hh.jpg) , I assigned _groupsList = groupsList; then I initialized _groupsList by calling the function initGroups(); But you can see that groupsList is not changed its count is still 0, where as the count of _groupsList is 3. What am I doing wrong ?